# Get session service using IServiceProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, dependency-injection

I need to access session variable in ConfigureService method in ASP.NET Core 1.0 using IServiceProvider.

I have a service that is initialized with delegate/lambda expression that can return value from any place. In this context this lambda expression argument should return value from session once called.

Here is example code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

     services.AddTransient<IMyService>(serviceProvider =>
            {
                return new MyService(() => {
                        var session = serviceProvider.GetServices<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession>().First();
                        return session.GetString("CompanyID");
                    }
                );
            }

      );

      // Add framework services.
      services.AddMvc();
      services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
      services.AddSession();
}
```

My session is configured fine (I can get/set values in controllers). However, I cannot fetch the service from IServiceProvider. I cannot find what type should be provided to GetServices method to get a service that will find session.

Comment: Where are you resolving the service?

Comment: This service is provided in controller constructor like CompanyController(MyService src) { ... }

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession` implements `ISession`, but `ISession` isn't registered with the DI system so you can't resolve it directly.

But as you can see [here](http://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/SessionMiddleware.cs#L100-L102), the `ISession` is created during the execution of the Session middleware and put into the list of features (a list where a middleware can put data that can be consumed later on during the request). The `HttpContext.Session` property is populated from the `ISessionFeature` set during the session middleware call. So you can access it from `HttpContext`.

You'll need to register the `IHttpContextAccessor` with

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

and resolve this, then access it's `HttpContext.Session` property. You have to do the registration, because the `IHttpContextAccessor` isn't registered by default anymore since RC2, as mentioned in this announcement [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/190) on the GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks, it works. After adding the line you suggested: services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>(); I can get the session object using: serviceProvider.GetServices<IHttpContextAccessor>().First().HttpContext.Session;

Comment: Actually you can use the singular version of it, then you don't need to call the `First()`at the end. `serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().‌​HttpContext.Session`