# Current Session in Controller dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In startup.cs I have

```
            services.AddScoped<ISession>();
```

In controller I have

```
private HttpContect _session;
public AccountController(ISession session)
    {
        _session.session = session;
    }
```

but `Isession` is not a service so it cannot be `AddScoped`(will result in an error). I also tried `IHttpAccessor` but that didnt work either(also gives an error). How can we have the HttpContext.sessions in controller dependency injection? (Is that even a a good practice?)

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear.

Comment: I explained everything whats unclear?! How do you put current sessions in your controller dependency injection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get session service using IServiceProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552601/get-session-service-using-iserviceprovider)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you want to access current session we could directly use it in the asp.net core mvc controler's HttpContext value. There is no need to inject the session by yourself. We just need to enable the session service in the startup.cs.

Asp.net core will call the session service automatically and we could use the session method to get it.

You could refer to below sources  to know how it works.

1. We should update the startup.cs ConfigureServices method add this:

   ```
        services.AddSession();
   ```

This AddSession method [sources codes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Middleware/Session/src/SessionServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) is:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddSession(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (services == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        }

        services.TryAddTransient<ISessionStore, DistributedSessionStore>();
        services.AddDataProtection();
        return services;
    }
```

You could find it add the ISessionStore, ISessionStore is used to create the session store.

2.We should add the the UseSession() to the startup.cs Configure(IApplicationBulider app, ...) method:

```
        app.UseSession();
```

The [source codes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Middleware/Session/src/SessionMiddleware.cs) like this:

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var isNewSessionKey = false;
        Func<bool> tryEstablishSession = ReturnTrue;
        var cookieValue = context.Request.Cookies[_options.Cookie.Name!];
        var sessionKey = CookieProtection.Unprotect(_dataProtector, cookieValue, _logger);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sessionKey) || sessionKey.Length != SessionKeyLength)
        {
            // No valid cookie, new session.
            var guidBytes = new byte[16];
            RandomNumberGenerator.Fill(guidBytes);
            sessionKey = new Guid(guidBytes).ToString();
            cookieValue = CookieProtection.Protect(_dataProtector, sessionKey);
            var establisher = new SessionEstablisher(context, cookieValue, _options);
            tryEstablishSession = establisher.TryEstablishSession;
            isNewSessionKey = true;
        }

        var feature = new SessionFeature();
        feature.Session = _sessionStore.Create(sessionKey, _options.IdleTimeout, _options.IOTimeout, tryEstablishSession, isNewSessionKey);
        context.Features.Set<ISessionFeature>(feature);

        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Features.Set<ISessionFeature?>(null);

            if (feature.Session != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    await feature.Session.CommitAsync();
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    _logger.SessionCommitCanceled();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.ErrorClosingTheSession(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You could find it read the data and set it into httpcontext.

So, there is need and there is no build-in way to inject the session into controller. We could directly use it by using `HttpContext` or inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` and use its `HttpContext`.

Answer (score -1):

You have alternative "IHttpContextAccessor"
just add in the startup file and use it in your controller

```
 services.AddScoped<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

in your controller :

```
 private IHttpContextAccessor httpContext;

        public Const(IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext)
        {
           
            httpContext = _httpContext;
        }
```

your session

```
 httpContext.HttpContext.Session
```

Comment: I get the following error `Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' from root provider.'`

Comment: @iamaaarianme -- Add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;` to the top of the file.